# Add Selector to UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uibutton

I have  `ViewController` and then two different `ViewControllers` that extend that main `ViewController`, one for the iPhone and the other for the iPad.

The iPad's `ViewController` instantiates a separate extended `UIView` and sets it as its own view. That view has some buttons, which I want to add its selector methods as some methods in the main `ViewController`. How can this be achieved?

So here's a way to visualize this:

```
Main ViewController
| iPhone ViewController
| iPad ViewController
  | Some UIView Class    --> Button must invoke method in Main View Controller
```

**EDIT:**
I do not use interface builder at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, there's no trick to it.

If you define `(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender` in the main view controller, it's inherited by the iPad view controller subclass.  Therefore specifying it as a selector belonging to `self` when the iPad view controller sets up its button should work fine.

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify, I do not use interface builder at all.

Comment: That should make no difference to the inheritance logic.  If the button is being defined in the controller's code the `addTarget:` method can still specify `self` and the selector in the superclass.

Comment: Oh - the button is not in the iPad's view controller's class. It's in a UIView class which is initialized (and set to `self.view`) in the iPad's view controller which inherits the main view controller. So the `UIView` is a different class that extends a custom `UIView`.

Comment: In that case, I'd create a custom initializer for the custom UIView so that I could pass the view controller reference in and have it available as the button's target.  (Or, if I was really ambitions, create a "MyButtonDelegate" protocol.)

Comment: I found a way to put it in the iPad's view controller, thus saving all the hassle. Using your suggestion above, of just referring to `self`, it says it cannot find that selector method. Even though the method is in the iPad's VC super VC.

Answer (score 23):

Your question is a bit confusing, but if I understand, you can use code like this to setup the button:

```
[button addTarget:yourObject action:@selector(yourMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

So you set **addTarget** to the instance of `MainViewController`, and set the **action** to whatever the method is you want to call inside `MainViewController`. You should be able to do this in Interface Builder too as long as your method accepts `IBAction`.

Comment: addTarget should be an instance of your ipad viewcontroller, then this works perfectly

Comment: How would I create `yourObject`? It is the VC of which that view ends up in. In this case, I cannot do: `ThisVC *vc = [ThisVC alloc] init]` because it has been already created. I need a way to reference the main view controller from the UIView. The `UIView` is not created within the iPad's view controller, but in a different class (see my comment below).

Comment: You should make a property in your app delegate (or anywhere you see fit) to hold onto a pointer to that view controller. So in your app delegate .h file, put: `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *myViewContoller;` and set that whenever you create your view controller. Than you can always get to your app delegate and find the view controller like this: `[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] myViewController];`

Comment: generally yourObject is "self"