# how to say "if a button is pressed, then do this" objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I want to be able to say "when nextButton is pressed, output". I have an IBAction for the button too, I don't know what to do with it.

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                URLForResource: @"artList" withExtension:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (string) {
   NSArray *lines = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    //output first definition to screen
    _wordDefBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_wordDefBox.text, lines[0]];
    _wordDefBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%s",_wordDefBox.text, "\n"];
    _wordDefBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_wordDefBox.text, lines[1]];


}

//error checking
 else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to load string from %@: %@", myURL, error);
}
```

Comment: What does the code you posted have to do with your question? If you already have an IBAction for your button, then you already have your answer. Whatever code is in your action method will be run when the button is pressed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Selector to UIButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758926/add-selector-to-uibutton)